# Compton background color

Tags: compositing

I just installed compton, but now my screen background is gray rather than black. I'm using i3wm and no background image. Compton is basically just dimming inactive windows.

How can I change this back to black?

Compton config (not cleaned up yet):

```
# Shadow
shadow = false;

no-dnd-shadow = true;
no-dock-shadow = true;
clear-shadow = true;
shadow-radius = 7;
shadow-offset-x = -7;
shadow-offset-y = -7;
# shadow-opacity = 0.7;
# shadow-red = 0.0;
# shadow-green = 0.0;
# shadow-blue = 0.0;
shadow-exclude = [ "name = 'Notification'", "class_g = 'Conky'", "class_g ?= 'Notify-osd'", "class_g = 'Cairo-clock'" ];
# shadow-exclude = "n:e:Notification";
shadow-ignore-shaped = false;
# shadow-exclude-reg = "x10+0+0";
# xinerama-shadow-crop = true;

# Opacity
menu-opacity = 0.8;
inactive-opacity = 1.0;
# active-opacity = 0.8;
frame-opacity = 0.7;
inactive-opacity-override = false;
alpha-step = 0.06;
inactive-dim = 0.2;
# inactive-dim-fixed = true;
# blur-background = true;
# blur-background-frame = true;
blur-kern = "3x3box"
# blur-kern = "5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"
# blur-background-fixed = true;
blur-background-exclude = [ "window_type = 'dock'", "window_type = 'desktop'" ];
# opacity-rule = [ "80:class_g = 'URxvt'" ];

# Fading
fading = false;
# fade-delta = 30;
fade-in-step = 0.04;
fade-out-step = 0.04;
# no-fading-openclose = true;
fade-exclude = [ "class_g = 'Conky'" ];

# Other
backend = "xrender"
mark-wmwin-focused = true;
mark-ovredir-focused = true;
# use-ewmh-active-win = true;
detect-rounded-corners = true;
detect-client-opacity = true;
refresh-rate = 0;
vsync = "none";
dbe = false;
paint-on-overlay = true;
# sw-opti = true;
# unredir-if-possible = true;
# unredir-if-possible-delay = 5000;
# unredir-if-possible-exclude = [ ];
focus-exclude = [ "class_g = 'Cairo-clock'" ];
detect-transient = true;
detect-client-leader = true;
invert-color-include = [ ];
# resize-damage = 1;

# GLX backend
# glx-no-stencil = true;
glx-copy-from-front = false;
# glx-use-copysubbuffermesa = true;
# glx-no-rebind-pixmap = true;
glx-swap-method = "undefined";
# glx-use-gpushader4 = true;

# Window type settings
wintypes:
{
  tooltip = { fade = true; shadow = false; opacity = 0.75; focus = true; };
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that `xsetroot` uses `XSetWindowBackground()` for setting the background and compton is incompatible with this.

Try to use `hsetroot` instead of `xsetroot` (it has the same syntax with `-solid` etc).

If you want to learn more see the following compton issue report:

https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues/162

Comment: Where do you get `hsetroot`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the wallpaper in compton, but in your `.xinitrc`. Try adding `Esetroot -s /path/to/your/wallpaper.png` for a wallpaper, or `xsetroot -solid #CC0000` for a color.

Comment: The thing is, I have never set this. i3wm has defaulted to black. Setting the color with xsetroot had no effect - it's still gray.

Comment: Using fluxbox here, `fbsetbg` worked where `xsetbg` did not. (Yes, I'm setting a background image, not a colour.)